# How to get ajax commenting system to work from different directory?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, ajax

I have a page and I am trying to add an ajax commenting system to it.  When I put all the code in the /comment directory into root, my new pages can implement the script.  However, if I make another directory, say /books, then link to the pages inside the /comment directory, It will not post the comments.  I can display them and access the javascript page, but I can't not make new comments.  What is causing it to fail.  I think it is somewhere in the javascript file...  I didn't want to include so much code if you need to see anything else, let me know and I will post it.  I will include the php file and the javascript file up one directory, and into another...  Any tips would be great.  Here is my page:

```
<?php

// Error reporting:
error_reporting(E_ALL^E_NOTICE);


include('../comments/connect.php');
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/comments/comment.class.php');



/*
/   Select all the comments and populate the $comments array with objects
*/

$comments = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY id ASC");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $comments[] = new Comment($row);
}

?>

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style.css" />
</head>
<body>

<ul id="nav">
    <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
</ul>
<div id="container">

    <div id="content">

<?php

/*
/   Output the comments one by one:
*/

foreach($comments as $c){
    echo $c->markup();
}

?>

<div id="addCommentContainer">
    <p>Add a Comment</p>
    <form id="addCommentForm" method="post" action="">
        <div>
            <label for="name">Your Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />

            <label for="email">Your Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />

            <label for="url">Website (not required)</label>
            <input type="text" name="url" id="url" />

            <label for="body">Comment Body</label>
            <textarea name="body" id="body" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>

            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</p>

    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../comments/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the javascript...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* The following code is executed once the DOM is loaded */

    /* This flag will prevent multiple comment submits: */
    var working = false;

    /* Listening for the submit event of the form: */
    $('#addCommentForm').submit(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        if(working) return false;

        working = true;
        $('#submit').val('Working..');
        $('span.error').remove();

        /* Sending the form fileds to submit.php: */
        $.post('submit.php',$(this).serialize(),function(msg){

            working = false;
            $('#submit').val('Submit');

            if(msg.status){

                /* 
                /   If the insert was successful, add the comment
                /   below the last one on the page with a slideDown effect
                /*/

                $(msg.html).hide().insertBefore('#addCommentContainer').slideDown();
                $('#body').val('');
            }
            else {

                /*
                /   If there were errors, loop through the
                /   msg.errors object and display them on the page 
                /*/

                $.each(msg.errors,function(k,v){
                    $('label[for='+k+']').append('<span class="error">'+v+'</span>');
                });
            }
        },'json');

    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think problem is on the javascript side, your post goes to a relative url you should replace it with an absolute url:

```
/* Sending the form fileds to submit.php: */
$.post('submit.php',$(this).serialize(),function(msg){//<- replace submit.php with absolute url
...
```

Comment: the submit path was the problem.  Thank you very much!

Comment: I changed the submit path back just to see if the other guys solution is what actually fixed it.  And it was.  so, he takes the cake.

Comment: lol im so sorry, but I forgot to save it.  You are the true solution. My apologies.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are connecting to your database with an include, using a relative path:

```
include('../comments/connect.php');
```

That would be the first thing to change, it could be something like:

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/comments/connect.php');
```

In general, look for relative paths and see if you can change them to absolute paths, either relative to the root of your server for php files or relative to the web-root for javascript files.

Comment: don't seem to be the problem here

Comment: I am making all the connections, but for some reason, I cannot pass the form data to submit.php and on into the database.  I don't think this will solve my problem..

Comment: Have to say it was actually the doc roots in the submit.php  I put the absolutes at the top and that fixed it!

Comment: @Paxwell Glad you got it fixed!

Comment: Never mind, it was the above guys answer that fixed it.  the path in the java w . as the breaking point.  The paths were working.  I just forgot to save after changing his back.  When I did it broke again.  But thanks.  I implemented this through out as well

Answer (score 3):

You would normally have your comment script at a URL that doesn't change, i.e. www.domain.com/comments. Then, you can either fetch comments for a page with a GET request (specifying the page, URL or other unique identifier via a query string parameter), and then the ability to post a comment with, well, a POST request.

This way, your comments module is completely separate from your application and you don't need to go through every script it's included in if you need to say, change your database details or a file path.

At it's simplest, you could have a PHP file that looks like this for your comments script:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

switch (strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])) {
    case 'get':
        // return comments for page in JSON format
    break;
    case 'post':
        // post new comment; return result in JSON format
    break;
}
```

And then in your HTML view files:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="comments"></div>
    <form action="http://domain.com/comments.php" method="post" id="new-comment">
      <!--rest of your form here-->
    </form>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON('http://domain.com/comments.php?page_id=YOUR_PAGE_ID', function(comments) {
          $.each(comments, function(index, comment) {
            // add comment to #comments div
          });
        });

        $('#new-comment').submit(function() {
          $.post('http://domain.com/comments.php', $(this).serialize(), function(response) {
            // act on your form depending is response was success or not
          });
          return false;
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You could also wrap the above in a plugin, and then just add your comments widget to your page with a one-liner, i.e. `$('#comments').nameOfYourCommentsPlugin();`.

Hopefully that's helpful enough for you to build a working solution.

Comment: This was helpful, though not what I was looking for.  Thanks. +1

Comment: @Paxwell I know. I realized after posting I went on a bit of a tangent. Sorry!

Comment: Your solution is strangely elegant :D, I like it *voteup*, but may confuse newbies.